# How to set token in mysql and let the token work only in one hour?

Tags: mysql, sql

Use for such as "email_reset_password function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only implementation I remember I saw to that case was to have an additional column that would have a date. That date would contain the information regarding the token validation.
I mean, when you insert the token, you also insert the date it will still be valid (in your case current date and time + 1 hour), and then, you can use that information to verify if it expired or not.